# Should you test primitive functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am currently rewriting a large data framework for my company. My company has a basically nonexistent testing policy and I want to change that, but I am very new to testing software. Thus I wanted to ask the following question -

If I have the following function:

```
def read_attributes(annotation_file=IMPORTED_PATH):
    attributes = {}
    with open(annotation_file) as ga:
        for idx, line in enumerate(ga):
            fields = [field.strip() for field in line.split('\t')]
            if idx == 0:
                continue
            else:
                attributes[fields[0]] = fields[6] #0 - sample, 6 - tissue

    return attributes
```

I don't see the point in actually unit-testing it, if I have a previous test that checks if file at **IMPORTED_PATH** actually exists.

I have tried to test whether certain keys are present in the resulting **attributes** dictionary, but I see that as volatile because file at **IMPORTED_PATH** can change it's values. I could also write an if statement checking whether **fields** variable has the necessary amount of entries, but that is more of an internal check than a test.

Should I test this and how would I go about it?

Comment: I would look at this way: **is there really nothing in the `read_attributes` function that can get broken**? I'd say that the answer is clearly **no, it can break**. Remember, it's not only about checking that something works now. It's also about ensuring that future modifications of the function don't introduce breaking changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing 2 different tests.

1. A file in `IMPORTED_PATH` exists (You already have a unit-test for this one).
2. `read_attributes` works as expected.

To check that `read_attributes` works as expected, I would create an annotation_file in a known location (maybe some `test_resources` folder).

This file should not be changed.

Since you know the contents of the file, the test should run something similar to the following:

```py
def test_read_attributes():
    KNOWN_ANNOTATION_FILE = "path\to\constant\annotation\file"
    expected_attributes = <expected_values> # can also be read from a file

    attributes = read_attributes(annotation_file=KNOWN_ANNOTATION_FILE)

    assert attributes == expected_attributes
```

I hope I understand your concerns correctly and it answers your question :-)

PS

If you are new to testing in python, I recommend pytest (it has a native plugin in PyCharm)

Comment: Alternatively separate the function into 2, one of which reads a file and another one parses its content. Now you can test parsing logic separately.

Comment: @Saar Thanks for providing examples. I will separate the function into two as per suggestion.